# How does one update a ROS package with a different source and repo considering one does not have access to the old repo?

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pocketsphinx has a package for ROS which is no longer maintained and has not been updated in many years. Now, I am working on an updated version of ROS package of pocketshpinx for the parent organization, CMUSphinx.

The package can be found here: http://wiki.ros.org/pocketsphinx
The old repo is present here: https://github.com/mikeferguson/pocketsphinx
While the new one is here: https://github.com/Pankaj-Baranwal/pocketsphinx/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263751/how-does-one-update-a-ros-package-with-a-different-source-and-repo-considering-one-does-not-have-access-to-the-old-repo?/) by [PankajBaranwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/29651/pankajbaranwal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2017-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution myself.
Detailed instructions for this exact problem is provided here:
http://wiki.ros.org/MaintenanceGuide#Claiming_Maintainership

---

Originally posted by [PankajBaranwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/29651/pankajbaranwal/) with karma: 96 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2017-12-01**:
Then please close the question. And another advice: please write shorter titles on your questions :-)

**Comment by [PankajBaranwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/29651/pankajbaranwal/) on 2017-12-01**:
Thanks. Will keep that in mind in the future